# ASIHttp which function send data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

in ASIHTTPRequest class

I debug  - (void)main  method of the NSOperation with wireshark . I want to find which method  send data.

But i debug to the end of startRequest in main method  of NSOperation. I can't  grab  any  data.

Because the read stream opens a socket connection with the server specified by the myUrl parameter when the CFHTTP request was created, some amount of time must be allowed to pass before the stream is considered to be open. Opening the read stream also causes the request to be serialized and sent.

base the above document of apple  about "Communicating with HTTP Servers"

the most chance to send data is  the below code .But it don't. I can't find something  in wireShark.

```
CFStreamClientContext ctxt = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
if (CFReadStreamSetClient((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kNetworkEvents, ReadStreamClientCallBack, &ctxt)) {
    if (CFReadStreamOpen((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream])) {
        streamSuccessfullyOpened = YES;
    }
}
```

where  send  data ????  like socket send or sendto function.

Comment: ??? What do you want ???

Comment: I  want to find method like CFReadStreamOpen((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream])  to communicate with server that send data  to server.like in socket sendto  or send function.

Answer (score 2):

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

and

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

If your program is for command line, just use  `[request startSynchronous]` in `main`, because if you use asynchronous request, the main thread continue, when main thread terminate, maybe asynchronous request do nothing.